# Где может находиться вирус, если по месту, где он указан его уже нет, но он запускается?

Tags: bash, ssh, вирусы, антивирус

Ко мне несколько дней назад закинули руткит/майнер/брутер на сервер. Я поменял все пароли, запретил доступ как переписыванию файлов конфигурации ssh, удалил исходник вируса и его с сервера. А так же написал антивирус, который по паттерну его ищет и убивает. И он все еще его находит. Я уже перебрал все файлы конфигурации, которые я знаю, но не могу понять, как он запускается при подключению по ssh, если сам оригинальный файл /usr/bin/bash не менялся. Подскажите пожалуйста еще места, где он может быть исходя из лога ниже:

```
Nov  6 11:48:51 gen safeguard[679844]: [*] Starting check of bash-fuckoff pattern
Nov  6 11:48:51 gen safeguard[679844]: [Check 1] No processhider found
Nov  6 11:48:51 gen safeguard[679844]: [Check 2] No processhider found
Nov  6 11:48:51 gen safeguard[679844]: tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:50224     137.184.28.195:http     ESTABLISHED 679808/-bash
Nov  6 11:48:51 gen safeguard[679844]: Found -bash running at pid 679808
Nov  6 11:48:51 gen safeguard[679844]: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  6 11:48 /proc/679808/exe -> /usr/bin/-bash (deleted)
Nov  6 11:48:51 gen safeguard[679844]: Killing  679808
Nov  6 11:48:51 gen safeguard[679844]: Successfully killed
Nov  6 11:48:51 gen safeguard[679844]: [*] Stopping check of bash-fuckoff pattern
```

Причем если заходить под шеллом sh, он не запускается.

Lsof:

```
    Found -bash running at pid 1259943
-------LSOF-----------
COMMAND     PID USER   FD      TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
-bash   1259943 root  cwd       DIR      8,1     4096        2 /
-bash   1259943 root  rtd       DIR      8,1     4096        2 /
-bash   1259943 root  txt       REG      8,1  2365616   508977 /usr/sbin/-bash
-bash   1259943 root  DEL       REG     0,14          57204116 /anon_hugepage
-bash   1259943 root  DEL       REG     0,14          57203978 /anon_hugepage
-bash   1259943 root    0r     FIFO     0,12      0t0 57202639 pipe
-bash   1259943 root    1w      CHR      1,3      0t0        4 /dev/null
-bash   1259943 root    2w      CHR      1,3      0t0        4 /dev/null
-bash   1259943 root    3r      CHR      1,9      0t0        9 /dev/urandom
-bash   1259943 root    4u      REG      8,1        0   267435 /tmp/.lock
-bash   1259943 root    5u  a_inode     0,13        0     8973 [eventpoll]
-bash   1259943 root    6r     FIFO     0,12      0t0 57203548 pipe
-bash   1259943 root    7w     FIFO     0,12      0t0 57203548 pipe
-bash   1259943 root    8r     FIFO     0,12      0t0 57203545 pipe
-bash   1259943 root    9w     FIFO     0,12      0t0 57203545 pipe
-bash   1259943 root   10u  a_inode     0,13        0     8973 [eventfd]
-bash   1259943 root   11u  a_inode     0,13        0     8973 [eventfd]
-bash   1259943 root   12u  a_inode     0,13        0     8973 [eventfd]
-bash   1259943 root   13r      CHR      1,3      0t0        4 /dev/null
-bash   1259943 root   14u     IPv4 57203680      0t0      TCP 192.168.1.2:47192->vps-57ca5d6a.vps.ovh.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov  7 21:17 /proc/1259943/exe -> /usr/sbin/-bash       Killing  1259943
Successfully killed                                                              Found fake bash. Removing it
```

PSTREE

```
-------PSTREE--------
-bash(1266362)-+-{-bash}(1266364)
               |-{-bash}(1266365)
               |-{-bash}(1266366)                                                               |-{-bash}(1266367)
               |-{-bash}(1266368)                                                               |-{-bash}(1266393)
               `-{-bash}(1266394)
```

Comment: ¿Зачем тратить время на поиск вируса? Отформатируйте диск и поставьте систему начисто.

Comment: На этой системе вертится одно приложение, которое просто так не перенести на другой сервер. Слишком много компонентов, так что сервер нужно сохранить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он сам себя выдал. В общем если у кого-то будет этот вирус, уже есть инструкция.
[image: PwnRIG]

[Решение проблемы с этим вирусом](https://gist.github.com/Gsealy/2c8ad20f49009c649f662b14e6825d51)

P.S> Но я все-таки его зареверсил и нашел много интересного. Всем кто пытался помочь, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из лога там есть ещё один файл, который записывает этот файл, потом делает exec и сразу unlink.

Я бы начал с включения [аудита](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10107) на этот путь. Возможно эксплоит ещё гдето лежит. в планировщике или в вэб сервере.

Comment: Включил через sudo auditctl -w /usr/bin/-bash -p warx, но все равно ничего:
roo@gen:~# ausearch -f /usr/bin/-bash
<no matches>

P.S. Перед тем как азапустить ausearch, вошел снова в ssh, убедился, что по аудиту safeguard он запускался только что, но все равно пусто.

Comment: похоже делает exec по удаленному файлу. посмотри этот дескриптор чем-то открыт?

Comment: safeguard[757955]: lsof: status error on /usr/bin/-bash: No such file or directory - похоже не находит его

Comment: В proc смотри пид, в пиде смотри exe чтоль или как-то так. На эту штуку и делай lsof

Comment: И смотри не меняется ли номер inode этой штуки. Если меняется, то значит она где-то упакована и распаковывается каждый раз

Comment: Добавил вывод lsof в вопрос

Comment: Интересный случай) а может всё-таки баш заражен?

Comment: Ну если заходить через ssh, но сначала через -t /bin/sh, а потом уже там запускать bash, то все в порядке и все работает. Такое ощущение, что ssh + bash заражен, а другие комбинации не заражены. Могу вирус скинуть если хотите ) У меня он лежит разобранный в hexninja.  Пытался его декодировать, но payload странный

Comment: Создал сам файл /usr/bin/-bash с помощью touch, через секунду в нем появилось содержимое, быстро сделал a=r /usr/bin/-bash и chattr +i /usr/bin-bash и теперь он не может запускаться и не может удалиться и перезаписаться. Получается, что я его поймал. Причем в auditctl глянул, там только мои команды есть, других команд нет, что весьма странно.

Comment: `root@gen:~# file /usr/bin/-bash
/usr/bin/-bash: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, no section header`
`root@gen:~# file /usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

Comment: но какой-то процесс его пытался запустить, если не сам себя поддерживает, то надо поискать ещё

Comment: Проблема в том, что я искал. Я не понимаю, какой процесс записал в файл его содержимое